# Adding navigation bar on all the views. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

This is a basic question, but I couldn't really find a answer.
In my swift app, I decide to add navigation bar on all the view controller  in storyboard.

Do I have to manually add in the bar for each of them, or is there any clean way I could add them in automatically/programmatically only once?
(I just want to add the bar with title, not even the buttons or the navigation function.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have to manually add the custom bar to each of them.

However, you can make it cleaner by defining a class for that custom view. For example `HeaderBar` then you do all the setup  in this class itself (`HeaderBar.swift`). When you add this bar to any view controller, all you need to do is simply drag and drop from storyboard and typing class name `HeaderBar` and it is ready to go, no more further configuration.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the Navigation Controller puts a navigation bar on every one in your storyboard. Just drag one onto your storyboard, connect your first controller as the root to it, and make every following view controller connected by "Show" segues to the last. Now all your view controllers should have a navigation bar on top of them.

You can access their navigation controller with this property in a view controller:

```
self.navigationController
```

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462), it'll give you more details on how navigation controllers / view controller hierarchy works.

Comment: Hey brimstone, thx for your help. I will take a look at this tutorial, but all I wanted was really the top bar only, I don't even need the navigation itself. 
So what do you think is the best way?